# Accessing Facebook API Page Insights with Python

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm currently an administrator of a Facebook Page and I'm attempting to access some insights from it and I'm having lots of trouble gaining any access to the API. At the moment, it currently returns no data. Can anyone figure out why?  Trying to get a code written that'll let me input whatever metrics I am searching for under the 'metric' part of the parameters.

```
graph=facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token)
page_info=graph.get_object('me') # returns metadata for page
page_ID=page_info['id'] # returns the page ID to be used in calling the URL

base='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9'
node='/'+ page_ID + '/insights'
url=base+node
parameters={'period':'week','access_token':token,'metric':'page_impressions'}
object=requests.get(url,params=parameters).text.encode('utf-8')
data=json.loads(object)
print data
```

This returns the following (I've taken out the access token where it would be):

> {u'paging': {
>
> u'next':  u'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/1509164045966534/insights?access_token=(my_hidden_token)&metric=page_impressions&period=week&since=1495255384&until=1495514584',
>
> u'previous': u'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/1509164045966534/insights?access_token=(my_hidden_token)&metric=page_impressions&period=week&since=1494736984&until=1494996184'
>
> },
>
> u'data': []}

Comment: If it is a public page(not owned by you) only currently page_fans_country or page_storytellers_by_country is available via insights.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/insights

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
base='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9'
node='/'+ page_ID + '/insights/page_impressions'
url=base+node
parameters={'period':'week','access_token':token}
object=requests.get(url,params=parameters).text.encode('utf-8')
data=json.loads(object)
print data
```

metric is not parameter :)

Comment: Changing my code to this returns me the same thing.

Comment: You are the owner of this page?