# Getting Facebook Insights with Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-insights

I am trying to get the impressions from my Facebook page using python, I am just asking for impressions to make it work but it will be great to get all the data from a post. My code looks like this:

```
import facebook
import requests
import json

# Give the date Unixtime format
a = u'12/30/2018'
b = u'12/31/2018'
since = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%m/%d/%Y")
until = datetime.datetime.strptime(b, "%m/%d/%Y")

# Parse and make the URL
token = 'MyAccessToken'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version=3.1)
page_info = graph.get_object('me')
page_id = page_info['id']
base = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2'
node = '/' + page_id + '/insights/page_impressions'
url = base + node
parameters = {'period': 'week', 'access_token': token,'since': since, 
              'until': until}
object1 = requests.get(url, params=parameters).text.encode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(object1)

print(data)
```

I am getting no error, just the data array is empty:

```
{'data': [], 'paging': {'previous': 
 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/pageID/insights?period=week&access_token=MyAccessToken&metric=page_impressions_unique&since=1547994299&until=1548253499', 'next': 
 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/pageID/insights?period=week&access_token=MyAccessToken&metric=page_impressions_unique&since=1548512699&until=1548771899'}}
```

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814428/get-insights-data-of-facebook-page) post and I have 'read_insights' permission for this token and admin/owner permissions of the page, I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105005/accessing-facebook-api-page-insights-with-python) post about it but the answer is not complete and the same thing happens.

> **Does anyone know how properly retrieve the data of Facebook Insights using Python?**

Comment: Step 1: Debug your access token to verify it does indeed include all the permissions you think it does.

Comment: Yes, It does. It was already check before asking.

Comment: did you try specifying since and until parameters?

Comment: I just tried and it gives me this error, Parameter until: Must be a unixtime or a date/time representation parseable by strtotime()

Comment: @luschn so i try this:
`a = u'01/01/2018'
b = u'12/31/2018'
since = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%m/%d/%Y")
until = datetime.datetime.strptime(b, "%m/%d/%Y")`

But now i get this error:  _{'error': {'message': 'Unsupported operation', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 100_

Comment: not sure if the timespan between since and until can be THAT long...

Comment: I also try with just one day buy it didnt work